# Showing only the closest location in Turf.js with MapBox

Tags: node.js, mapbox, turfjs

Hi I have a JS script that I would like some help on. I have a MapBox script where I am trying to find the closest data point to the address the user types into the search box. When a user types in the address it flys to the nearest point (using Turf.js) to that location and centers on it. However, when that happens, I only want that point to be visible on the map if the user decides to scroll around on the map. Any pointers on what part of the script I should edit to only display that specific one?

```
   /**
   * Assign a unique id to each store. You'll use this `id`
   * later to associate each point on the map with a listing
   * in the sidebar.
  */
  stores.features.forEach(function(store, i){
    store.properties.id = i;
  });

  /**
   * Wait until the map loads to make changes to the map.
  */
  map.on('load', function (e) {
    /**
     * This is where your '.addLayer()' used to be, instead
     * add only the source without styling a layer
    */
    map.addSource("places", {
      "type": "geojson",
      "data": stores
    });

    /**
     * Create a new MapboxGeocoder instance.
    */
    var geocoder = new MapboxGeocoder({
        accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken,
        mapboxgl: mapboxgl,
        marker: true,
        bbox: [-77.210763, 38.803367, -76.853675, 39.052643]
    });

    /**
     * Add all the things to the page:
     * - The location listings on the side of the page
     * - The search box (MapboxGeocoder) onto the map
     * - The markers onto the map
    */
    buildLocationList(stores);
    map.addControl(geocoder, 'top-left');
    addMarkers();

    /**
     * Listen for when a geocoder result is returned. When one is returned:
     * - Calculate distances
     * - Sort stores by distance
     * - Rebuild the listings
     * - Adjust the map camera
     * - Open a popup for the closest store
     * - Highlight the listing for the closest store.
    */
    geocoder.on('result', function(ev) {

      /* Get the coordinate of the search result */
      var searchResult = ev.result.geometry;

      /**
       * Calculate distances:
       * For each store, use turf.disance to calculate the distance
       * in miles between the searchResult and the store. Assign the
       * calculated value to a property called `distance`.
      */
      var options = { units: 'miles' };
      stores.features.forEach(function(store){
        Object.defineProperty(store.properties, 'distance', {
          value: turf.distance(searchResult, store.geometry, options),
          writable: true,
          enumerable: true,
          configurable: true
        });
      });

      /**
       * Sort stores by distance from closest to the `searchResult`
       * to furthest.
      */
      stores.features.sort(function(a,b){
        if (a.properties.distance > b.properties.distance) {
          return 1;
        }
        if (a.properties.distance < b.properties.distance) {
          return -1;
        }
        return 0; // a must be equal to b
      });

      /**
       * Rebuild the listings:
       * Remove the existing listings and build the location
       * list again using the newly sorted stores.
      */
      var listings = document.getElementById('listings');
      while (listings.firstChild) {
        listings.removeChild(listings.firstChild);
      }
      buildLocationList(stores);

      /* Open a popup for the closest store. */
      createPopUp(stores.features[0]);

      /** Highlight the listing for the closest store. */
      var activeListing = document.getElementById('listing-' + stores.features[0].properties.id);
      activeListing.classList.add('active');

      /**
       * Adjust the map camera:
       * Get a bbox that contains both the geocoder result and
       * the closest store. Fit the bounds to that bbox.
      */
      var bbox = getBbox(stores, 0, searchResult);
      map.fitBounds(bbox, {
        padding: 100
      });
    });
  });

  /**
   * Using the coordinates (lng, lat) for
   * (1) the search result and
   * (2) the closest store
   * construct a bbox that will contain both points
  */
  function getBbox(sortedStores, storeIdentifier, searchResult) {
    var lats = [sortedStores.features[storeIdentifier].geometry.coordinates[1], searchResult.coordinates[1]]
    var lons = [sortedStores.features[storeIdentifier].geometry.coordinates[0], searchResult.coordinates[0]]
    var sortedLons = lons.sort(function(a,b){
        if (a > b) { return 1; }
        if (a.distance < b.distance) { return -1; }
        return 0;
      });
    var sortedLats = lats.sort(function(a,b){
        if (a > b) { return 1; }
        if (a.distance < b.distance) { return -1; }
        return 0;
      });
    return [
      [sortedLons[0], sortedLats[0]],
      [sortedLons[1], sortedLats[1]]
    ];
  }

  /**
   * Add a marker to the map for every store listing.
  **/
  function addMarkers() {
    /* For each feature in the GeoJSON object above: */
    stores.features.forEach(function(marker) {
      /* Create a div element for the marker. */
      var el = document.createElement('div');
      /* Assign a unique `id` to the marker. */
      el.id = "marker-" + marker.properties.id;
      /* Assign the `marker` class to each marker for styling. */
      el.className = 'marker';

      /**
       * Create a marker using the div element
       * defined above and add it to the map.
      **/
      new mapboxgl.Marker(el, {offset: [0, -23]})
      .setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)
      .addTo(map);

      /**
       * Listen to the element and when it is clicked, do three things:
       * 1. Fly to the point
       * 2. Close all other popups and display popup for clicked store
       * 3. Highlight listing in sidebar (and remove highlight for all other listings)
      **/
      el.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        flyToStore(marker);
        createPopUp(marker);
        var activeItem = document.getElementsByClassName('active');
        e.stopPropagation();
        if (activeItem[0]) {
          activeItem[0].classList.remove('active');
        }
        var listing = document.getElementById('listing-' + marker.properties.id);
        listing.classList.add('active');
      });
    });
  }

  /**
   * Add a listing for each store to the sidebar.
  **/
  function buildLocationList(data) {
    data.features.forEach(function(store, i){
      /**
       * Create a shortcut for `store.properties`,
       * which will be used several times below.
      **/
      var prop = store.properties;

      /* Add a new listing section to the sidebar. */
      var listings = document.getElementById('listings');
      var listing = listings.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
      /* Assign a unique `id` to the listing. */
      listing.id = "listing-" + prop.id;
      /* Assign the `item` class to each listing for styling. */
      listing.className = 'item';

      /* Add the link to the individual listing created above. */
      var link = listing.appendChild(document.createElement('a'));
      link.href = '#';
      link.className = 'title';
      link.id = "link-" + prop.id;
      link.innerHTML = prop.address;

      /* Add details to the individual listing. */
      var details = listing.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
      details.innerHTML = prop.city;
      if (prop.phone) {
        details.innerHTML += ' · ' + prop.phoneFormatted;
      }
      if (prop.distance) {
        var roundedDistance = Math.round(prop.distance*100)/100;
        details.innerHTML += '<p><strong>' + roundedDistance + ' miles away</strong></p>';
      }

      /**
       * Listen to the element and when it is clicked, do four things:
       * 1. Update the `currentFeature` to the store associated with the clicked link
       * 2. Fly to the point
       * 3. Close all other popups and display popup for clicked store
       * 4. Highlight listing in sidebar (and remove highlight for all other listings)
      **/
      link.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        for (var i=0; i < data.features.length; i++) {
          if (this.id === "link-" + data.features[i].properties.id) {
            var clickedListing = data.features[i];
            flyToStore(clickedListing);
            createPopUp(clickedListing);
          }
        }
        var activeItem = document.getElementsByClassName('active');
        if (activeItem[0]) {
          activeItem[0].classList.remove('active');
        }
        this.parentNode.classList.add('active');
      });
    });
  }

  /**
   * Use Mapbox GL JS's `flyTo` to move the camera smoothly
   * a given center point.
  **/
  function flyToStore(currentFeature) {
    map.flyTo({
        center: currentFeature.geometry.coordinates,
        zoom: 15
      });
  }

  /**
   * Create a Mapbox GL JS `Popup`.
  **/
  function createPopUp(currentFeature) {
    var popUps = document.getElementsByClassName('mapboxgl-popup');
    if (popUps[0]) popUps[0].remove();

    var popup = new mapboxgl.Popup({closeOnClick: false})
      .setLngLat(currentFeature.geometry.coordinates)
      .setHTML('<h3>Sweetgreen</h3>' +
        '<h4>' + currentFeature.properties.address + '</h4>')
      .addTo(map);
  }

</script>
```